# Step function returns false

Tags: javascript, sql.js

This is my javascript code sample.

```
var sql = require('sql.js');

var db = new sql.Database();

sqlstr = "CREATE TABLE hello (a int, b char);";
db.run(sqlstr); 

sqlstr = "INSERT INTO hello VALUES (?, ?);"

var stmt = db.prepare(sqlstr);

stmt.bind([0, 'hello']);
console.log("INSERT: ",stmt.step());
stmt.reset();
stmt.free();
```

Why is step statement returning "FALSE" here ? The record however goes into database successfully.

Comment: Well, that's an `INSERT`, so it is a non-query -- it doesn't return any row. Looks like `step()` is right in returning `false` here.

Comment: If thats the case then how do I check if the record has been inserted? Is there an equivalent of SQLITE_DONE we use in C?